# Joomla:: File image does not exist

Tags: joomla

I am working on a Joomla project where I am new to Joomla.

i have problem that cannot open my site, the error is :-

```
File images/stories/zamalek/s3201221131442.jpg does not exist.
```

my link :-

```
http://zamalekcity.com/zamalek-news/664--3-.html
```

i am use joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Since your website doesn't display anything, I would guess that you have a problem with your template. Try using an IDE like eclipse for searching the path it tells you it's not finding in your code. Maybe it's a typo.

Your system is asking for an image so you should go to `images/stories/zamalek/` and make sure that file is actually there. Remember that if you're working on a Linux server, it distinguishes between lowercase and uppercase letters.